# sveltkit direct links do not work in AWS s3

Tags: amazon-s3, sveltekit

I am using sveltekit to publish a static website to Amazon S3. Everything works fine when I run local. When I run on s3 I can connect to `example.com` and when I click on the link to `example.com/page1` it works fine. However if I type `example.com/page1` directly in my browser I get a 404.

Here is my svelte.config.js

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: preprocess(),

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter()
    }
};

export default config;
```

Comment: did you manage to solve this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: some suggestions here on this https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/4278

Answer (score 1):

This is likely related to S3 attempting to serve `index.html` for a `page1` directory: `/page1/index.html`.

Looking at example `svelte.config.js` you posted, `page1` is probably `page1.html`, which S3 won't know about.

Adjust any `page.js`/`page.server.js` (or `layout.js`/`layout.server.js`) files to export `const trailingSlash = 'always'` option. This will generate `page1/index.html`, `about/index.html`, etc, which S3 will then be able to directly look up instead of relying on Svelte's routing system (loaded on the homepage only).

For example:

```js
import { error } from "@sveltejs/kit";
import api from "../../api";

// ADD THIS EXPORT
export const trailingSlash = "always";

export async function load({ params }) {
  const data = await api(endpoint);
  if (!data) {
    throw error(500, "Page Error");
  }
  return {
    ...data,
  };
}
```

Relevant documentation:

- https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#trailingslash
- https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/trailingslash